# Does the Bay of Ice freeze in winter, allowing the others to simply walk around the wall?

Tags: game-of-thrones

This question was marked as a duplicate of another, but I'm trying to ask a different question that is not addressed. Please keep reading.

The other question asks whether or not the Others can simply swim or sail around the wall. I argue this is a moot point, since by latitude and geography, I can't imagine the Bay of Ice doesn't simply freeze over in the winter. Is there any canon mention of this one way or the other?

If it does freeze, the Others could just walk south from the Frozen Shore to the Wolfswood and Deepwood Motte, completely bypassing both the wall and the mountains.

Comment: *"Assuming that the Bay of Ice freezes solid in the winter,..."* Do you have canon sources that bodies of water near the Wall freeze solid in winter? That would really help your question. :-)

Comment: The wall freezes..

Comment: Related: [Can others swim across the Narrow Sea to threaten Essos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133066/54887)

Comment: @RichS, that is literally the question that I'm asking. I haven't read the books, so I don't know one way or the other. If it snows as far south as Kings Landing, though, I can't imagine the Bay of Ice wouldn't freeze. Not to mention the name is the Bay of Ice.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. It's distinct enough from the other question. This one is about whether White Walkers could walk around the Wall if the Bay of Ice froze over. The other question is about whether White Walkers can swim.

Comment: @GSnow "Bay of Ice" may describe ice flows instead of a completely frozen bay. I haven't read the books either, so I can't provide sources from the books (if there are any). You might want to edit your question saying you want an answer with quotes from the books. :-)

Comment: @RichS I'd say that given that GRRM says Others have an extraordinary way of building things out of ice, the answer would be the same. They could build an ice-bridge and move across it. Plus remember that during long night, Others threatened Essos as well, which proves that they were able to project force across the narrow sea. If they can do that, a simple bay should be a piece of cake. Regardless to the fact the canon answer is the same, _**We do not know**_. Neither Show nor Books have covered it so all we have is speculation.

Comment: Not to mention, Mooz has made many interesting points there. This is just a narrowed down sub-question of the more generic question that why can't Others bypass the wall through the sea. And therefore is bound to get the same answer. Which in turn makes this a duplicate. (Just providing my reasoning as the first close voter)